# Creating a code element and appending it to .codeblockDiv does not create the code tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I made a code block that you can edit and create a new code block, but the problem is that It's not creating the `code` tag. Here is my code:

```html
 <style>
 html, body {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.codeblockDiv {
  width: 50%;
}
.codeblock {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(207, 207, 207) 16%, rgb(252, 252, 252) 79%);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
}
.edit {
  top: 0;
  right: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.cancel {
  top: 0;
  right: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}
.new {
  left: 9px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
 </style>
 <body>
 <button class="new" onclick="newCodeblock()">
  New
 </button>
 <button class="edit" onclick="editCode()">
  Edit
 </button><br>
 <code class="codeblock" id="codeBlock">
 &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
       &emsp;&lt;html&gt;<br>
        &emsp;&emsp;&lt;head&gt;<br>
        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&lt;meta charset&#61;&ldquo;UTF-8&rdquo;&gt;<br>
        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&lt;title&gt;Example&lt;&sol;title&gt;<br>
        &emsp;&emsp;&lt;&sol;head&gt;<br>
 &lt;body&gt;<br>
 &emsp;&lt;div&gt;<br>
 &emsp;&emsp;&lt;p&gt;This is in a &lt;code&gt; tag&lt;&sol;p&gt;<br>
 &emsp;&lt;&sol;div&gt;<br>
 &lt;&sol;body&gt;<br>
        &emsp;&lt;&sol;html&gt;
        </code><br>
<script>
function editCode() {
  var x = document.getElementById('codeBlock');
  x.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
  var y = document.createElement('button')
  y.innerHTML = "Cancel";
  y.className = "cancel";
  document.body.appendChild(y);
  y.addEventListener('click', function() {
   x.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false")
   y.remove()
  })
  
}
function boldText(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17 && e.keyCode == 66) {
   let textBox = document.querySelector('.codeblock');
   textBox.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }
}
function newCodeblock() {
 var z = document.createElement('code'); 
 var h = document.createElement('button');
 z.className = "codeblock";
 z.innerHTML = "Write Here"
 z.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

 h.innerHTML = "Save";
 h.addEventListener('click', function() {
  z.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
  h.remove();
 })
 document.querySelector('.codeblockDiv').appendChild(h);
 document.querySelector('.codeblockDiv').appendChild(x);
}
</script>
 <div class="codeblockDiv">
  
 </div>
 </body>
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/YT_Xaos/aso407wt/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `newCodeblock` function is referencing a non-existent variable `x`

if you change

```
document.querySelector('.codeblockDiv').appendChild(x);
```

to read

```
document.querySelector('.codeblockDiv').appendChild(z);
```

Your `newCodeblock` function will run successfully